# Filling white pixels with interpolation (Python/openCV)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a grayscale image with some white color noisy (something like salt and pepper). I would like to fill these white pixels (>230 px value) with nearest neighborhood pixel values.

Below is the example. Any solutions?

[image]

Comment: What is your rationale ? Do you expect to get a "better" image after this filtering ?

Comment: White salt pixels are a noise and should not have been there. I am trying to remove it without impacting any other pixels

Comment: Why are they there ? Why do you thing that "erasing" them will improve the image ?

Comment: please review [ask]. show your research.

Comment: I did not mention I was going to 'improve' image

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a filter like `cv2.medianBlur(noisyImage, ksize)`. Adjust the `ksize` value (major to 3), and see if the white dots minimize.

If you don't want to affect other pixels you can search this pixels that are major than 230 and modify their value. Try this:

```
h, w = img.shape
imgResult = numpy.zeros((h,w,1),numpy.uint8)
h_mask, w_mask  = (5, 5)
threshold = 230
for j in range(h):
    for i in range(w):
        if img[j,i] > threshold:
            ymin = (j - h_mask) if (j - h_mask) >= 0 else 0
            ymax = (j + h_mask) if (j + h_mask) < h else (h - 1)
            xmin = (i - w_mask) if (j - w_mask) >= 0 else 0
            xmax = (i + w_mask) if (j + w_mask) < w else (w - 1)
            imgResult[j,i] = cv2.mean(img[ymin:ymax,xmin:xmax])[0]
        else:
            imgResult[j,i] = img[j,i]
```

where `img` is your input image, modify `h_mask`, `w_mask`, and `threshold` depending on the result that you want. Using these values I get:

[image]

Comment: Blurring is not my interest since it will impact the other pixels

Comment: Create a mask from the pixels >230. Use that mask to blend between the original and medianBlur versions such that the median is used where the mask is white and the original is used where the mask is black. Or use the mask with cv2.inpaint()